# How to make sure that you don't start a service twice android

Tags: android, service

Is there a way to check that the service is not already running before starting it?

If it could be in the onCreate() of the service it will be even better,

Thank you!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

fix it with a boolean/flag in the service.
 (A service can only be started once)

Comment: You shouldn't have to do this. It may be indicative of another problem. Are you doing something in the service's onStartCommand() that you should be doing in onCreate() instead?

Comment: Nobody can get answer from your answer

Answer (score 36):

You can't start a service twice, it will remain running if you try to start it again. [Link to the Android docs.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29)

Comment: it must be due to something else which causes the crash

Comment: Per docs: "Note that multiple calls to Context.startService() do not nest (though they do result in multiple corresponding calls to onStartCommand()), so no matter how many times it is started a service will be stopped once Context.stopService() or stopSelf() is called;"  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle

Comment: So if I start my service 200 times in a for loop, it will continue to run as if I started it once?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Why not test it out?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested on Android 9 (API 28) that you can start the same service with the same `Intent` as many times as you want:

```
onCreate() {
    startMyService();
    startMyService();
    startMyService();
    startMyService();
    startMyService();
    startMyService();
    startMyService();
    startMyService();
    startMyService();
    startMyService();
}
private void startMyService() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
}
```

One way to avoid this is to stop it before starting it by passing the identical `Intent`:

```
private void startMyService() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    stopService(serviceIntent); // <<<<< this line makes sure that you don't start it twice or more times
    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
}
```